# How can I access third div when clicked only by class in Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have four div of same class, but I want to access each div when clicked only by class name for any further action only by java script/Jquery

```
     <div class="myclass">something</div> 
     <div class="myclass">something 2</div>
     <div class="myclass">something 4</div>
     <div class="myclass">something 3</div>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What's your expected result?

Comment: What do you mean by *access*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using jquery class selector with on click handler

```js
$(function() {
  $('.myclass').on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myclass">something</div>
<div class="myclass">something 2</div>
<div class="myclass">something 4</div>
<div class="myclass">something 3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following jquery:

```
$(".myclass").click(function(e)
{
    var div = this;
});
```